# Please reopen, not a dupe! (Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

The following question:

[Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20078816/1369235)

...was closed as a dupe of this question:

[How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-string)

Despite the similar titles, the actual question asked in the second question regards characters in the files not being accepted by the Python interpreter due to not declaring the file as UTF-8. Furthermore, it seems that some answers ignored the actual question and replied to the title (which is good because that *would* have helped me) however they all mention either how to replace a single specific character, or how to *remove* (not replace) all non-ASCII characters.

In fact, I do link to that question in my own question and I mention why the answers given there do not answer the question. I also like to a few other similar questions with similar issues.

Please reopen my question as it is not a dupe, and due to the fact that no answer is given to the question asked.

**EDIT:** I see that the question has been reopened. Thank you!

Comment: I guess if you would edit title to more accurately reflect what's this question about, it would give you a better chance for reopening. And " ignored the actual question and replied to the title" smells like a bad approach on your side: ideally title should be an actual question, and body should be only needed to provide details, context etc.

Comment: @Mołot: You are correct, but that is a problem with the _other_ question, not mine. I don't want to go editing somebody else's question which has been there for quite some time, has significant reputation, and has an accepted answer.

Comment: As long as you are not altering the topic of a question, making title consistent with content should be perfectly all right. Well, I hope someone with higher rep will be bolder at editing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the title of the dupe to better reflect the actual question content:

[How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342000/1521227)

...and thus voted to reopen your question.

Comment: Nice job! Thank you!

Comment: Voted to reopen too.